# Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <txtUsernameReister.Text> in ID Column. Expected type is Int32

Tags: vb.net

When I run this program I get an error saying

> Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store
>    in ID Column.  Expected type is Int32.

I think it's because within my table the first column is the 1D which has a data type of Integer.

Is there any way I could inert the value of `txtUsername.Text` into the second column (which stores the usernames rather than the first ?

```
    Dim dataAdapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * FROM Ranking", ObjConnection)
    Dim cb As New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
    Dim datatable As New DataTable

    dataAdapter.Fill(datatable)
    dt.Rows.Add("txtUsernameReister.Text", dt.Rows.Count + 1) 'adds the id only along with a new record in the table ranking'
    da.Update(dt)
    MsgBox("Registration Succesful")
    Login.Show()
    Me.Hide()
```

Comment: your code doesnt use *the value of txtUsername.Text* but the string literal "txtUsername.Text".

Comment: Not for nothing, but your app should not have to be determining and setting the ID if it is supposed to be a unique identifier.  RowCount is a particularly bad idea because it can result in duplicate values once a row  is deleted.  Let the DB do its job and assign IDs, by using an AutoNumber column for ID.

Comment: Reading this a 3rd time, `first column is the 1D` maybe you also need to swap the order: `dt.Rows.Add(txtUsernameReister.Text, dt.Rows.Count + 1)` .  Rows count remains a very bad idea for a unique ID method.

Answer (score 0):

the reason why you're getting this is that, you have filled the `data table` specific index with integer values initially. now you want to fill same data table with different datatype values. So to achieve this you need to explicitly type cast using `CAST() or CONVERT()` function for that specific column to convert into `Int32` while selecting from database.